# linq joint type inference failed to call 'join' error

Tags: linq

i have 3 tables User, TeamMember and Assessment all three have the user_id column, User is linked to TeamMember by userid and TeamMember and Assessment are linked with user_id(TeamMember) & rater,rated(Assessment)

Im trying to join in with this

```
          from a in db.Assessments
                         join u in db.Team_Members on a.rated equals u.user_id
                         join u2 in db.Team_Members on a.rater equals u2.user_id
```

It's throwing this error

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Any idea what going on?

Comment: What are the types of `a.rated` / `u.user_id` and `a.rater` / `u2.user_id`

Comment: aha sorry i was refrencing the wrong column id thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure `a.rated` / `u.user_id` and `a.rater` / `u2.user_id` are the same type