# How to perform innner Join on Five Tables using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

```
gameScheduling db = new gameScheduling();

var query = from c in db.tblgroupDetail

    join g in db.groups on c.GroupId equals g.GroupId
    join t in db.Tournaments on c.TournamentId equals t.tournamentId
    and so on......
    select new {c.Name etc etc}
```

I have an error on join plz some useful suggestions.

Comment: Does "an error" have an error message?

Comment: Write here your actual code and table structure.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442967/how-do-you-do-multiple-inner-joins-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: the error is type inference failed in call join

Comment: Please post the full query... the error is likely in the "and so on" part

Comment: So On Means 2 tables are more to join like others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the types of your expression variables the same?
E.g.: are `c.GroupId` and `g.GroupId` both `int` or is one of them of type `byte`?

The types of the variables in your expressions must be of the same type if you want to compare them with each other.

Comment: Yes I have the same type Expression

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use .Value with the field name in the select clause....

Comment: i think there must be problem in your other part of query as this is just a pseudo code for it, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161496/linq-joint-type-inference-failed-to-call-join-error)`Click Here` and read it...

Comment: and do check the types also...

Answer (score 0):

I did one similar scenario it may help you please check below link

[Join two data table and return new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541437/join-two-datatable-using-linq-and-get-result-in-other-datatable)